# Gettin hash key for facebook app with keytools

Tags: android, facebook, openssl

So here is my problem.

When i run keytool to get the hash key it will give me the ;
openssl is not a valid command, program etc.

I have installed openssl and the path is:  C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\bin\openssl

Is that wrong?

How should i write the commandline?

I try to write it like this:

keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore 
| openssl sha1 -binary
| openssl base64

Doesnt work so i try like this:

keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore c:\Users\Richie.android\debug.keystore 
| openssl sha1 -binary
| openssl base64

Doesnt work....

should i specify the path to openssl or what should i do?

I´ve tried it in Cygwin also but i dont even got keytools to operate there ´cuase i dont know how to go to the right folder ( program files (x86)\Java\jre6\bin)

Any ideas?  I´m dying here....

Comment: how about pasting the error message instead of saying "doesn't work"?

Answer (score 1):

Hi Richie you have to write the path where is located your keystore and the openssl folder, this is the way i do...

I have installed OpenSSL in ::

> C:\openssl

the path and name of my Keystore is ::

> C:\android\gruporeforma.keystore

So this is what i write in the commandline ::

> keytool -exportcert -alias
>   gruporeforma -keystore
>   "C:\android\gruporeforma.keystore" |
>   c:\openssl\bin\openssl sha1 -binary |
>   c:\openssl\bin\openssl enc -a -e

Comment: Hi!Do you use the windows command tool? When i put it in it just says that "Program is not a valid command"  My path  is "c:program files (x86)\GnuWin32\bin\openssl" so it work.

Comment: yep just go to "start" -> "Run..." and write "cmd"; and your path must be ""c:\program files (x86)\GnuWin32\bin\openssl"

Comment: Got it to work!       keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey
 -keystore "c:\users\richie\.android\debug.keystore" | "c:\program files (x86)\g
nuwin32\bin\openssl" sha1 -binary | "c:\program files (x86)\gnuwin32\bin\openssl
" base64   Thanx man!!

Comment: that´s so cool your wellcome! don't forget accept my response as valid hehe! =D

Answer (score 0):

yes, you need to specify the path to openssl and keytool unless they're already in your PATH. the first command should work in Cygwin as typed, and if it doesn't you need to install the correct packages. or just continue with Windows, specifying the full path to each executable.

Answer (score 0):

better use this piece of code

```
  try {
        PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo("your.package",
                PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
        for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
            MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
            md.update(signature.toByteArray());
            Log.d("YOURHASH KEY:",
                    Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT));
        }
    } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {

    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {

    }
```